# New to ios. Where to start

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to `iOS`. A bit knowledge of `obj. C`.

So now from where I have to start?

I just want to go with basics of `objects` and `Class`. And how do we use property of `iOS`. 
And after that where should I move.

Please post details of `iOS` 6, not older version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Stanfords course cs193p. It is available for free on iTunes:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016

and has a community forum dealing with questions about the course:

https://piazza.com/open-classes/coding-together

The course consists of lectures including live demos, and also provides assignments (for self study).

Comment: The Stanford lectures are a great resource.

Answer (score 3):

This website is easy to start to program for iOS. I just started it two weeks ago with this website.

Also they have a cheat sheet to understand basic structure of obj-c.

They update their contents to new iOS versions frequently.

Hope it helps you.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: Agreed!!!
This is very good way to start off iOS programming, these tutorial are  seriously good.

Answer (score 1):

The official site is always the place to start :) ...

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

(But you will soon find that learning Objective C is a pre-requisite ... so if you don't know it yet, try http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you to take a look at Lynda's "[iOS SDK Essential Training (2012)](http://www.lynda.com/iOS-tutorials/iOS-SDK-Essential-Training/92179-2.html)" while you are  having a couple of coffees, it is a very smooth introduction to iOS.

Then go ahead for [Ray Wenderlich Blog](http://raywenderlich.com/) for some well covered tutorials.

[iOS developer:tips]; is a nice place to follow for quick tips.

And finally come back here for your questions, eventually.

Comment: Sorry, as you didn't mention that you were looking only for free resources, I included that one too.

Comment: Thanks A lot for this. Ray blog is helpful.